# Is it possible to find such a $n\in \mathbb {Z^{+}}$, for given value of $\lambda;$ $\frac {2^{10+\lambda+n}-2^{10+\lambda}-144759}{3^{10}}<349525$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, discrete-logarithms

I'm trying to solve a mathematical problem. I expressed the point where I was stuck with the modular arithmetic. Here is my problem;

Is it possible to find such a $n\in \mathbb {Z^{+}}$,  for given value of $\lambda,$

> $$\frac {2^{10+\lambda+n}-2^{10+\lambda}-144759}{3^{10}}<349525$$
>
> $$2^{10+\lambda+n}-2^{10+\lambda}-144759 \equiv 0 \pmod {3^{10}}$$
>
> Where, $\lambda =1,2,3,...,39366.$

Is there a mathematical way to solve this problem?..I don't know. But, I tried only random value of $\lambda$ and I used discrete logarithm calculator. After a few unfortunate attempts, I gave up.

At least, is it possible to say the existence of such a ​​value of $\lambda$ without making a calculation?

https://www.alpertron.com.ar/DILOG.HTM

Comment: $\lambda$ is given and $n$ is sought or the other way around?

Comment: @Ihf You are right..(sorry for bad English)

Comment: Which is one is given then? Your last paragraph seems to say that $\lambda$ is sought but the second paragraph  seems to say that $\lambda$ is given.

Comment: @Ihf  Please, can you edit my question?...$\lambda$ is given $1,2,3,4...$ and $ n$ is sought..

Comment: Unless I'm doing my math wrong $\lambda$ has an upper limit of $24$ doesn't it?  $ 2^{\lambda + 10}(2^n - 1) <349525*3^10 + 144759 < 2^{35}$ implies $\lambda + 10 \le 34$, right?

Comment: @fleablood Yes you are right..I've realized now.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
   2^{10+\lambda+n} - 2^{10+\lambda} - 144759 &\equiv 0 \pmod{3^{10}} \\
   1024 \cdot 2^{\lambda+n} - 1024 \cdot 2^{\lambda} - 144759 
      &\equiv 0 \pmod{3^{10}} \\
   1024 \cdot 2^{\lambda}(2^n - 1)  &\equiv 144759 \pmod{3^{10}} \\
   2^n - 1  &\equiv 13116 \cdot 2^{-\lambda} \pmod{3^{10}} \\
   2^n  &\equiv 1 + 13116 \cdot 2^{-\lambda} \pmod{3^{10}} \\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Isn't $\lambda$ fixed but $n$ that needs to be solved for?

Comment: Is this based on $2$ being a primitive root mod $3^{10}$ and $1+13116 \cdot 2^{-\lambda}$ being invertible mod $3^{10}$ ?

Comment: @lhf : Yes. and by $2^{-\lambda}$, I mean $(2^\lambda)^{-1} \pmod{3^{10}}$

Answer (score 2):

You can write the first as $$2^n-1\lt \frac {349525\cdot 3^{10}+144759}{2^{10+\lambda}}\\n \lt \log_2\left(349525\cdot 3^{10}+144759\right)-10-\lambda\\n\le24-\lambda $$
so there are very few $n$s to try.  If $\lambda$ is at all large there are not any.